# How to hook to function of woocommerce product export _regular_price?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to write function to upgrade standard woocommerce product export function of _regular_price meta field.
I have pricelist in 'csv' format where i have 'Currency' column. When pricelist is imported price is calculated based on 'Currency' of that product and currency rate stored in 'Options' table. I already done the import part.

But i do not know how to hook to standard woocommerce export function that exports '_regular_price' meta field.  I need  to get the price returned by that function
and divide it by currency rate and then return the value.

May be someone help ?
Thank you.

Comment: I tryied to  use this hook : woocommerce_product_export_product_column_single_product_regular_price
_single_product_regular_price - is the name of column with regular price.
But it does not work.
May be i should use this hook:
woocommerce_$THIS->EXPORT_TYPE_export_rows
???

Answer (score 0):

I found 'woocommerce_product_export_row_data' hook
and now i can refer to csv column like  $row['regular_price'] and change the data.

The next question that I faced is that woocommerce csv export rounds the price in csv. I do not like this very much.
But this will be next investigation.